# Radicale config: File contains no section headers

Tags: python, config, radicale

I am not very familiar with Linux / Debian but still trying to install radicale on my Raspberry Pi. The installation worked without problems but when I try to start the radicale service with `sudo systemctl start radicale` and connect to the web interface all I get is: "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."

When using `journalctl --unit radicale.service` to debug it shows me the following:

```
Jun 12 18:49:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started A simple CalDAV (calendar) and CardDAV (contact) server.
Jun 12 18:49:20 raspberrypi env[6299]: [2022-06-12 18:49:20 +0200] [6299] [CRITICAL] Invalid configuration: Failed to load config file '/etc/radicale/config': File contains no secti>
Jun 12 18:49:20 raspberrypi env[6299]: file: '/etc/radicale/config', line: 1
Jun 12 18:49:20 raspberrypi env[6299]: '.# -*- mode: conf -*-\n'
Jun 12 18:49:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: radicale.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 12 18:49:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: radicale.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As I understand it something is wrong with my section headers. But as I configured the /etc/radicale/config file as follows I don't know what the problem actually is:

```
[auth]
type = htpasswd
htpasswd_filename = /etc/radicale/users
htpasswd_encryption = bcrypt

[server]
hosts = 0.0.0.0:5232

[storage]
filesystem_folder = /var/lib/radicale/collections
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I haven't been able to find anything remotely similar to my problem on Google.

Comment: maybe you can run it manually in console to see more informations about problem.

Comment: If I understand error message - it has problem with first line `'.# -*- mode: conf -*-\n'` in file `/etc/radicale/config`. Maybe you have to remove it.

Comment: Thanks furas. Turns out I'm just too stupid to use `journalctl` properly. There was another error further down and it was easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Would help if your cure was listed.
I've just worked through the same and found the guide https://www.atlantic.net/dedicated-server-hosting/how-to-install-radicale-calendar-caldav-and-carddav-on-ubuntu-20-04/
I was using advised `filesystem_locking = true` but this is an unknown configuration option error
on commenting this out, the unit runs ok